# Get many results in different responds? Discord.py / SQLite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

So I was trying to create a `/modlogs` Command which would show others every Log of an User. This means `Warns, Mutes, Bans, Unmutes, Unbans`. I managed to find a way and store most Data. I am currently trying to get that Data and use it. My problem here is that the bot will not answer exactly like I want it to do.

**Before** showing my Code etc. I need to show you what I am trying to achieve first. So this is an example of I want to achieve:

[image]

So as you can see, after running the command, the Client will respond with some Data. `(Action, Date, Mod, Reason)`. And it also responds on different message which is also something that I want to achieve.

About my code, I have tried two different things.

**First:**

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def modlogs(self, ctx, user : discord.Member):

        db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT guild_id FROM modlogsdb WHERE user_id = {user.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            await ctx.channel.send("This user has no Logs.")
        elif result is not None:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT type FROM modlogsdb WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {user.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT reason FROM modlogsdb WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {user.id}")
            result1 = cursor.fetchone()
            await ctx.channel.send(f"TYPE: {str(result[0])} - REASON: {str(result1[0])}")
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

As you see, I have added both results, the problem here is that it should show every result inside of the Database but it only gets one single row.

[image]

Something like this, but there is more Data inside of the Database:

[image]

================================================================================================

**Second Try:**

After trying the First one I made some changes so:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def modlogs(self, ctx, user : discord.Member):

        db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT guild_id FROM modlogsdb WHERE user_id = {user.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            await ctx.channel.send("This user has no Logs.")
        elif result is not None:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT type FROM modlogsdb WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {user.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT reason FROM modlogsdb WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {user.id}")
            result1 = cursor.fetchall()
            await ctx.channel.send(f"TYPE: {str(result[0])} - REASON: {str(result1[0])}")
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

I basically added `fetchall()` so it get's every row and then tried it again. First Problem I got is that the respond was inside of brackets. Second Problem I got was that, the Reasons were in the same line. Something like this:

[image]

So any ideas how to avoid these or at least manage to get the info as I showed in the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

Your second SQL query

```
SELECT reason 
FROM modlogsdb 
WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} AND user_id = {user.id}
```

will return a list of all the reason the user was warned/muted/...

A better approach would be to get the reason of each type one by one, that is

```
SELECT reason 
FROM modlogsdb 
WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} 
  AND user_id = {user.id} 
  AND type = "Warning"
```

This will return all the reasons the user was warned.

Alternatively, I think if you use

```
SELECT type, reason 
FROM modlogsdb 
WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id} 
  AND user_id = {user.id}
```

you would get a list of tuple containing `[('Warning', 'Bad Words'), ('Warning', 'NSFW Emojis')]` or something similar

Comment: The last one did not work. As for the second one, it worked kinda. Still it does not work as I wanted it. First of all the reason looks like this `('Bad Words',)`. How can I remove the `(,)`. Also using `for user_id in result:` and then create a message for every user_id?

Comment: Well `a = ('Bad Words',)` is simply a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp), so you can use `a[0]` to access the string `"Bad Words"`